For a fixed angle of attack, can increasing your speed cause a stall?
Most sources (I've found while googling) discuss angle of attack as the primary factor for determining if a wing stalls, and that makes sense.  As a layperson I also hear about minimum stall speeds of aircraft but not maximum.  But I've been reading about how air flow detaches from the back of a car at higher speeds so it got me wondering why doesn't that happen with wings? or does it?
In particular, for a fixed angle of attack, why wouldn't an increasing airspeed eventually cause flow to separate and therefore stall the wing?
I realize that near and above the speed of sound weird things happen, but I'm more interested at lower speeds.

Posting this as a comment because it doesn’t really answer your question, but yes, they are called high-speed stalls. For a given angle of attack, the flow could be attached at a lower speed, and then separate at an increased speed.

Thanks.  I've found this question really hard to google but i find 90% is knowing the right words :)

This has to do with the so-called coffin-corner. See this answer, also from @Peter Kämpf. And this also relates to why fast aircraft fly using the Mach number in cruise: What is the reason for changing the speed reference (IAS or Mach number) with altitude?.

Normally, increasing speed reduces the impact of viscosity (expressed as the Reynolds number). Viscosity is the reason why airflow detaches, and less of it means that flow will stay attached to slightly higher angles of attack.
However, transsonic effects spoil this pretty picture: Once supersonic areas form around the wing, raising the speed will increase their size and the shock in which they end. Since a shock is a sudden deceleration of air, and deceleration helps to let flow separation occur, an initially weak shock without separation can become a stronger shock with flow separation downward of the shock when speed is increased. If that separation causes a sufficient reduction in lift or severe buffeting so flight cannot be maintained, a so-called high-speed stall will follow.
Below the transsonic speed range, there is only one edge case where flying faster at the same AoA could increase the risk of stall. But that needs the right definition of speed as true air speed: When climbing, the airplane needs to compensate for the decreasing air density by flying faster. Higher altitude also means lower air temperature, and this effect will reduce the Reynolds number of the flow over the wing, even at the same indicated airspeed. Not by much, but if you start just a bit above stall, the lower Reynolds number at a much higher altitude could help to get you into a stall.
See here for an answer about the change in Re with altitude.

@MichaelHall I've read the "eventually" part as the upper limit of the subsonic speed range. Flying higher gs is indeed the way to keep the same AoA, but then the limit will be structural, not aerodynamic. Higher speed equals higher Reynolds number, except you vary height to keep AoA constant at increasing TAS.

@MichaelHall Yes, the last sentence makes clear that an answer without transsonic effects is preferred. Now I added a paragraph, but to stall an airplane on purpose this way needs very precise flying and still air.

I’m having a hard time understanding why the changing Re number will allow the wing a higher AoA without stalling. The actual viscosity of the air stays the same regardless of speed, correct?

(it could be as simple as more turbulence (higher Re) causes flow to separate later but I’m thinking it’s more complicated)
